# How to save any file with PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt5, let's say I have a path to a given file or folder, would it be possible to save it in a location inputted by the user? I suppose it could also be a copy paste operation, where it copies the file or folder from one directory and pastes it to another.

I currently have the current:

```
def browseGeoFile(self):
    self.geoPath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Browse Geometry File", "C:/", "*.scdoc")
    self.textBoxGeo.setText(self.geoPath)
```

Now would it be possible to save this file at a location specified by the user?

Comment: I did not understand you, you could explain yourself better

Comment: try with  PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to have a button that would grab a file (could be any type of file) and save as somewhere else. I grabbed the path of the file needed to be saved, but I'm not sure if pyqt actually has a method to save said file.

Answer (score 0):

Saving a file in Python is completely independent from PyQt.
You could save a file with contents in `contents` at location `path` using this code:

```
with open(path, "w") as f: # use "wb" if writing binary data
    f.write(contents)
```

Comment: @rjayy Yes, as long as you use "wb" instead of "w" if you are writing binary data.